# How can I add IP restrictions to s3 bucket(in the bucket Policy) already having a User restriction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-policies

I have a few s3 buckets, for which I have given access to only a specific IAM user. I did it by setting the following bucket policies :

1. `Effect : "Deny"`
2. `NotPrincipal : { "AWS " : "<My_IAM_User>" }`

I'm able to access the buckets only from the IAM user, so the policy works as expected, but I also want to restrict the bucket access to only a specific IP. This IP is the ec2 IP address my server is running on. The policy values I've used is as :

```
"Condition": {
  "NotIpAddress": {
    "aws:SourceIp": [
       "<My_EC2_Server_IP_Address>"
    ]
  }
}
```

I was expecting the above policy would allow only my EC2 server to access the s3 bucket objects, but if I'm making a call from any other IP ( eg : running the server on my local machine and trying to access the buckets. ) it's still responds with valid objects from the bucket.
**The above policy does NOT seem to block any request to access the bucket is made from other random IP addresses.**

**My entire bucket policy looks like :**

```
{
    "Version": "<Version_value>",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "<Sid_value>",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "<My_IAM_User>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<My_Bucket_name>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "<My_EC2_Server_IP_Address>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My References :
1. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/block-s3-traffic-vpc-ip/
2. https://medium.com/@devopslearning/100-days-of-devops-day-11-restricting-s3-bucket-access-to-specific-ip-addresses-a46c659b30e2

Comment: You should include the entire policy (masking any sensitive data like IPs, IAM user ARNs, and the bucket name).

Comment: Sure @jarmod, I've added my entire bucket policy. Stuck on this from a long time, would be really helpful if I could get a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to deny all AWS credentials except a given IAM user and to deny all IP addresses other than a given IP, then I would write that policy as two, independent deny statements.

Something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "<Version_value>",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "deny1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "<My_IAM_User>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<My_Bucket_name>/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "deny2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<My_Bucket_name>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "<My_EC2_Server_IP_Address>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Be careful with the IP address condition. Unless you are using an Elastic IP, your EC2 instance's IP can change e.g. if you stop then restart the instance.

Also note: you should not be using IAM User credentials on an EC2 instance. Instead, you should be using IAM Roles.